# Join three text files based on multiple columns

Tags: perl, unix

I want to join three text files based on multiple columns in Unix

I want to use in Perl script though

**File1**

```
A|B|C|MIKE
D|E|F|BIKE
G|H|I|HELLO
```

**File2**

```
A|B|C|123
D|E|F|456
G|H|I|789
A|A|A|121
B|B|B|221
```

**File 3**

```
G|H|I|ABC
A|A|A|BCA
B|B|B|CBA
```

**Final ouput**

```
A|B|C|MIKE|123|
D|E|F|BIKE|456|
G|H|I|HELLO|789|ABC
A|A|A|121|BCA
B|B|B|221|CBA.
```

I don't want to use a script which creates some temp text files since each of my text file size is very big. Can I achieve this using `join` in Unix?

Comment: How big of your input files?

Comment: Are there really blank lines in your files?

Comment: each file is of size close to 80MB in dev environment which can b still bigger in production, I cant use temp variables like hashes since the file size too big to load into a hash

Comment: there are no blank lines in the input files

Comment: No `join` only joins on one column not more than that and please double check your output. Where is `121` and `221` from file 2 (last two lines) in your output.

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry u r right, 121 & 221 should be coming for A|A|A|121|BCA and B|B|B|221|CBA

Answer (score 2):

perl solution from command line,

```
perl -F'\|' -lane'
  BEGIN { $" = "|" }
  $v = pop @F;
  $h{"@F"} or push @r, "@F";
  $h{"@F"}[$i] = $v;
  $i++ if eof;
}{ 
  print "@$_" for map [ $_, @{$h{$_}}[0..$i-1] ], @r
' file1 file2 file3
```

output

```
A|B|C|MIKE|123|
D|E|F|BIKE|456|
G|H|I|HELLO|789|ABC
A|A|A||121|BCA
B|B|B||221|CBA
```

**EXPLANATION:**

Before printing output, script generates following `%h` hash structure,

```
$VAR1 = {
      'G|H|I' => [
                   'HELLO',
                   '789',
                   'ABC'
                 ],
      'D|E|F' => [
                   'BIKE',
                   '456'
                 ],
      'B|B|B' => [
                   undef,
                   '221',
                   'CBA'
                 ],
      'A|A|A' => [
                   undef,
                   '121',
                   'BCA'
                 ],
      'A|B|C' => [
                   'MIKE',
                   '123'
                 ]
    };
```

Comment: each file is of size close to 80MB in dev environment which can b still bigger in production, I cant use temp variables like hashes since the file size too big to load into a hash

Comment: @satya: 80MB isn't so big. How do you know you can't load it into a hash? have you tried it? How much memory does your computer have?

Comment: @jaypal didn't know you're familiar with foreign languages :)

Comment: @mpapec It came naturally after seeing this beauty. It took me almost 10 minutes to dissect it and I'm high on perl now `;)` QQ: the `[0..2]` piece in the `END` block is it just to add empty separators if fields were missing in third file?

Comment: @jaypal yes, for purists who like warnings it should be `map $_ //"", @{$h{$_}}[0..2]` to replace `undef` values with empty strings.

Comment: @mpapec I'd be tempted to use `@{$h{$_}}[0..$i-1]` or to `$i--` before the for loop so there isn't a hardcoded constant.

Comment: @Miller it makes sense.

Comment: @mpapec: Wouldn't it be easier to, erm, put it in a program file?

Comment: Not necessarily, some of the shortcuts would be lost unless shebang becomes something like `#!/usr/bin/perl -F'\|' -lan`

Comment: @mpapec: Using a regex instead of autosplit remove the need for `-l`, and the key doesn't need to be recombined from the first three fields. So you're left with `-n` which is no big deal

Comment: There is one more thing, script versions encourage `-w` and `strict` which in turn add its share to verbosity. Btw, you mean, regex replaces `-a`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic program that does what you ask, but if your files are truly huge then it may die from lack of memory.

The names of the three files are expected on the command line, so it should be run as

```
perl program.pl file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt > merge.txt
```

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @keys;
my %data;

my $i = 0;
while (<>) {
  next unless /\S/;
  my ($key, $val) = /(.+)\|(.+)/;
  push @keys, $key unless $data{$key};
  $data{$key}[$i] = $val;
}
continue {
  ++$i if eof;
}

for my $key (@keys) {
  print join('|', $key, map $_ // '', @{ $data{$key} }), "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
A|B|C|MIKE|123
D|E|F|BIKE|456
G|H|I|HELLO|789|ABC
A|A|A||121|BCA
B|B|B||221|CBA
```

Comment: each file is of size close to 80MB in dev environment which can b still bigger in production, please let me know if this works fine

Comment: @satya: I can't tell. You should try it. 80MB isn't so big

Comment: can u help me with awk for getting the same output, and also please consider all three files can have extra rows which does nt exist in other files but need to appear in output, Also please refer to the output file format since i have changed for the last 2 lines